# I am returning render but problem persists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi I am relatively new to React Native.
Anyways my problem is that I am trying to change the font of my text, and want to ensure that when the fonts have loaded, only then do I want the Loading screen to end.

However, I am getting this error :

> Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

> This error is located at:
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
> in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

This is my App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppNavigator from './src/navigation/Navigator';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import {AppLoading} from 'expo-app-loading';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isFontLoaded : false
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    await Font.loadAsync({
      "SemiBold" : require('./src/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
      "Medium" : require('./src/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
      "Regular" : require('./src/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf')
    });
    this.setState({isFontLoaded:true})
  }

 render(){

   return (
     (this.state.isFontLoaded === true) ? (<AppNavigator/>):(AppLoading)
   // AppLoading
   );
 }
```

}

If there anything else you require please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `AppLoading` a JSX element? If so, it should be wrapped with `<AppLoading />`

Comment: @choz I have tried this already at which I get the following error:

Comment: @choz 

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: Then check your `expo-app-loading` file, or at least post it here.

Comment: expo-app-loading is a library, and what should I exactly look for?

Comment: Common mistake there is that you're exporting your component as default in `expo-app-loading` - I'd like to confirm if you don't do that since you're importing in `App.js` with **named imports such as { AppLoading }**

Comment: @choz forgive me, but I dont understand what you want me to do.

Answer (score 1):

Import by the following way like

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'; // this way

render(){

  if(!this.state.isFontLoaded){
    return <AppLoading />
  }

  return <AppNavigator />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however, I am receiving this now

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: This error usually occurs when it has invalid import. Check your import in `import AppNavigator from './src/navigation/Navigator';` and `import {AppLoading} from 'expo-app-loading';`

Comment: Hey, so I did some research and I guess the right way of importing AppLoading is [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/), AppNavigator works perfectly fine as without AppLoading, the app runs as expected.

Now however, I am getting this error with the updated import for AppLoading:
'Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.'